# GCP How to delete automatically generated OAuth clients?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, google-oauth, google-cloud-iam

In `GCP console => APIs & Services => Credentials => OAuth 2.0 client IDs`

I have some OAuth clients that I can't delete, they have a yellow triangle notice, which said:

> This automatically generated OAuth client ID is required for your
>   project. It can't be modified.

In my case, they were created by some of my Apps Script projects

So how can I remove them?

Comment: By deleting the apps script project

Comment: That's what I thought, but it's not true for my case. My apps script projects are bound to some forms. So when I delete the form, the project is also deleted. But the OAuth client is not deleted

Comment: Is it deleted from the trash too?

Comment: @TheMaster: yes, I empty all trash in Apps script page, Drive and even Forms. But maybe the reason is that I deleted the Form directly without deleting the bound script first (the bound script was also deleted along with the Form), that causes this problem.

Comment: Ok. If you delete the bound script first, then, does the oauth client get deleted? If you're sure this is a bug, you may [create a issue](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) in issue tracker

Comment: I tested again and it doesn't even delete the OAuth client if I delete the apps script project separately. Now each time I add a new apps script into my existing GCP project, a new OAuth client is created and I can't delete it :D I will report this issue

Comment: When you report it, please post the link as a comment here.

Comment: @AMolina: Hi, I posted the issue here https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/141070617